# Image Description on Hover Image Link

Tags: image, text, hyperlink, hover

I have a page with 9 images. Each image links to page about that project. I want the project name and a faded color to appear when one hovers over the image. I cannot figure out if this is something that I can do with the hover definition of the link style, or if I need to use javascript. I also do not know if I need multiple divs overlapped-- expecially because I want the fade color to cover the entire image, but the text to be left-indented.

Below you will find the divs of the top row of images as just place holders.

```
<div id="Wrapper">
<div id="images">
<div id="thumbnails_row1">
<div id="houses_01"><div class="site_nav_left">PROJECT TITLE</div class="site_nav_left"></div>
<div id="houses_02"><div class="site_nav_right">PROJECT TITLE</div class="site_nav_right"></div>
<div id="houses_03"><div class="site_nav_right">PROJECT TITLE</div class="site_nav_right"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65kpT/)

### Html

```
  <div id="wrapper">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"/> 
    <div id="Descprition">
    Image Description
    </div>    

   </div>
```

### Css

```
#Descprition{
    display:none;
}

img:hover + #Descprition{

    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y3Vyb/

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="thumbnail-image" />
    <div class="thumbnail-caption">This is a caption</div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="thumbnail-image" />
    <div class="thumbnail-caption">This is a caption</div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="thumbnail-image" />
    <div class="thumbnail-caption">This is a caption</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail{
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail-caption{
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: none;
}

.thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-caption {
  display: block;
}
```